# The page is showing some error with Reactve components

Tags: angular8, angular-reactive-forms

```
<input type="text" name="" id=""
             class="form-control" [formControl]='fname'
             placeholder="Enter your name">
```

and this is the error i am getting 
ERROR in src/app/myform/myform.component.html:12:54 - error TS2339: Property 'fname' does not exist on type 'MyformComponent'.

```
12                  class="form-control" [formControl]='fname'
                                                        ~~~~~

  src/app/myform/myform.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './myform.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component MyformComponent.
```

Comment: still now u face the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormControl  } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form = new FormGroup({
  fname : new FormControl(''),
  });

  onsubmit(){
     //submit button
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<label>
  Name:
  <input type="text" formControlName="fname"  placeholder="Enter your fname">
</label>
</form>
```

app.module.ts //module

```
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 0):

On your typescript you need to add the following function to get the value from your form:

```
get fname(){
   return this.formName.get('fname')
}
```